# How to encrypt a generic dictionary?

Tags: .net, generics, encryption, dictionary

Could someone provide a starting point for encrypting a generic dictionary in .NET?

**UPDATE** Basically I'm storing a bunch of string values with string keys. This dictionary is storing quite a few items though. I'm not sure whether encrypting the content would be better vs encrypting the dictionary.

Comment: You want it encrypted after serialization or simply encrypt the content?

Comment: @Tedd Probably after serialization due to the amount of objects stored in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net) on encrypting/decrypting strings.

If you want to encrypt the whole Dictionary object you first need to copy it to a SortedList<string, string> or similar. XmlSerialization doesn't support IDictionary-objects (neither does KeyValuePair).

Here is a [wrapper class](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx) for Dictionary that supports serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx)

And may be use a simple XOR encryption like [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/8b53894c-a889-4914-8c46-122980cc44ae/simple-xor-encryption.aspx) (if that serves your purpose) or use some build-in .net classes for encryption.